# c++ overloading of operator this

Tags: c++, string, overloading, operator-keyword

I use WTL CString class. This class has a single overloaded operator:

```
operator LPCTSTR() const
{
    return m_pchData;
}
```

so I used it like this:

```
CString sText = _T("I like CString!");
TRACE("%s", sText);
```

and I got:

```
Output: I like CStrings!
```

But after I added some own specific conversion methods and operators:

```
operator LPWSTR() const
{
    return ConvertStringToWide();
}
```

and

```
operator LPSTR() const
{
    return ConvertStringToAnsi();
}
```

and now I get instead of:

```
Output: I like CStrings!
```

this:

```
Output: &%?....
```

after making a few test I found out that CString now instead of calling operator LPCTSTR() and returning m_pchData it returns the this pointer of the class!
So I always get the pointer to the class and not to m_pchData.

So my question is: How can I tell CString class to use by default operator LPCTSTR() and not return the this pointer?

Comment: Can you create a minimal and complete example of your problem?  From the above, you are calling some macro `TRACE` (which wraps some unknown functions, probably involving C-style variadics) and you have modified someone else's `CString` (did you do so locally or globally in your project?).  Without a [sscce](http://sscce.org/), I'd have to duplicate your exact environment to figure out what is going on.

Comment: My guess would be that it's Win32 API code. `CString` is MFC's string class and `TRACE` is a VC/Windows macro. Note that this is just a clarification; the minimal self-contained sample is still a very good idea.

Comment: Calls to variadic functions such as `printf` will never cause user-defined conversions to be called.  How is `TRACE` defined?

Comment: I'm guessing the return type of `ConvertStringToWide` is a LPWSTR. Have you correctly allocated the memory? ie, you're not returning a pointer to some temp buffer? Also, you should be returning const pointers `LPCWSTR`.

Comment: @yzt: He said it's WTL, not MFC.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Right you are! I think Microsoft has several `CString` classes. This page seems to say that one is part of ATL and another is in MFC (and they might be at least partly incompatible):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5bzxfsea.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by passing a class instance to a variadic function.

Realize that the program never called `operator LPTSTR`, before or after your additions. The compiler does not know what "%s" means (the function implementation does). It just dumps the instance onto the stack, and the function sees %s, grabs four bytes off the stack and believes them to be a `TCHAR*` pointer.

Your program used to work more or less by accident: `CString` class happens to contain a TCHAR* pointer as its only member, and so its memory representation is indistinguishable from that a raw pointer. Well, actually, it's not an accident: the class was carefully designed to look this way, precisely because MSVC programmers are used to being able to pass `CString` instances to printf and such; there's a lot of code floating around doing (illegally) the same thing you are doing.

Anyway, my educated guess is that your problem started not when you added more methods to your version of `CString` (whether overloaded operators or otherwise), but when you added more **non-static data members**, thus breaking the carefully constructed system of smoke and mirrors.

Comment: To be fair, it is undefined behavior that MSVC is free to define how it likes, which includes magically working.

Comment: @Yakk: Is there a doc page making it well-defined (obviously in a non-portable manner)?

Comment: @Igor: Thank you very much, thats correct. I thought there is an option to define a default operator for this pointer: somesthing like "operator this() { return m_byMyData; }"